# Add special options to layout Flutter

Tags: user-interface, dart, flutter, alignment

I have this Code:

```
new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 20.0,
          ),
          alignment: FractionalOffset.centerRight,
          child: new GestureDetector(
                child: new Text('Forgot password?', style: new TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF2E3233))),
              ),
        ),
        new Container(
          width: 300.0,
          height: 45.0,
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: const Color(0xFF2E3233),
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(30.0)),
            ),
            child: new Text("Sign in",style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,letterSpacing: 0.3,),),
        ),
        new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 20.0,
          ),
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          child: new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new GestureDetector(
                child: new Text('Don\'t have an account?', style: new TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF2E3233))),
              ),
              new GestureDetector(
                child: new Text('Register.', style: new TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF84A2AF), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                onTap: moveToRegister,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Thats the result:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bqu2tv6rej0ejlt/Screenshot_20181104-171155.png?dl=0

But I want to achieve this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/754hempszq8xw5k/Screenshot_20181104-171202.png?dl=0

EDIT:
build method:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        // The containers in the background
        new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .44,
              color: const Color(0xFF84A2AF),
              padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 50.0,
              ),
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  new Image.asset('assets/app_logo_transparent_bg.png',
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .56,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Align(
                    child: new Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: buildSubmitButtons(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
              /*child: new Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: buildSubmitButtons(),
                ),
              ),*/
            ),
          ],
        ),
        // The card widget with top padding, 
        // incase if you wanted bottom padding to work, 
        // set the `alignment` of container to Alignment.bottomCenter
        new Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .33,
              right: 15.0,
              left: 15.0),
          child: new Container(
            height: 130.0,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: new Card(
              color: Colors.white,
              elevation: 2.0,
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: buildInputs(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

I tried so much but nothing seems to help? How I can align the Layout to the bottom...

Comment: add your build method please, to check the parent container

Comment: @diegoveloper See the updated Qestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few changes on your container (.56) , remove the `Align` widget, stretch your `Column` and add an `Expanded` item inside your `Column` to fill the space available.

```
            new Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .56,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            child: new Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Container(),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: new Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                    children: buildSubmitButtons(),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                            /*child: new Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            child: new Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: buildSubmitButtons(),
                            ),
                          ),*/
                            ),
```

Probably you will need to move your 'Forgot password' above the Expanded widget inside your Column.